# Java - cast not producing expected output

Tags: java, math, casting

```
public class Test { 

public static void main(String[] args) { 

int test = 1; 

System.out.println((double)(Math.pow(test/++test, 2)));

}
```

0.0 is printed to the screen. Why? Why is the cast not working as expected?

If test is declared this way...

```
double test = 1;
```

I get what I expect to print... 0.25.

Why?

I am new to programming and I'm playing around. Reading some of the documentation at this level is next to useless.

Comment: The cast happens too late. You have already written `(int) 1/ (int) 2` and produced `(int) 0`. Casting `0` to a `double` does not recover the truncated data.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing integer division. SO change the line to

```
System.out.println((Math.pow(test/(double)++test, 2)));
```

to do double division